# Selecting all details from Table A but only for the values that exist in Table B's top N rows

Tags: sql, oracle

This is using Oracle SQL.

**Edited my code, I had pasted it wrong.**

So I have two tables: class and event. Each class has a class_id that is also present in the event table. Some classes can exist as multiple events.

- First I need to order the classes by price descending, uses only the
  "class" table.
- Then I need to select only the top 4 most expensive classes from the
  previous result.
- Then I need to display all of the information from the event table
  for only the top 4 most expensive classes. This does not mean there will only be 4 rows, because as I said, some classes have multiple events.

I manage to get the first TWO bullet points to work, but as soon as I nest the first two SELECT statements into the final SELECT, it displays the events for ALL of the classes, even the ones that are not in the top 4.

```
SELECT x.*, 
       c.price, 
       c.class_name
       FROM event x, class c
       WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
                     FROM (SELECT price, class_name
                           FROM class
                           ORDER BY price DESC)
                     WHERE ROWNUM <=4)
       AND c.class_id=x.class_id;
```

So everything after the WHERE EXISTS works, but it's like it's ignoring the WHERE EXISTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you meant this:

```
SELECT x.*, 
       c.price, 
       c.class_name
       FROM event x, class c
       WHERE (c.price,c.class_name) IN (
                     SELECT price, class_name
                     FROM (SELECT price, class_name
                           FROM class
                           ORDER BY price DESC)
                     WHERE ROWNUM <=4)
       AND c.class_id=x.class_id;
```

Comment: Wow! This works! I tried an "IN" before too but I had put class_id in it and it wasn't working. This is a simple solution, thank you Jasen.

Comment: What if there are classes that have different class IDs, but the same price and class name?

Answer (score 1):

That is because it *is* ignoring the `exists`.  `Exists` returns true or false (or NULL).  Your clause is returning, normally, four rows.  These exist.  So, everything gets returned.  Perhaps you want this:

```
SELECT x.*, c.price, c.class_name
FROM event x JOIN
     (SELECT * 
      FROM (SELECT class_id, price, class_name
            FROM class
            ORDER BY price DESC
           ) c
      WHERE ROWNUM <= 4
     ) c
     ON c.class_id = x.class_id;
```

Comment: This tells me that the c.class_id is an invalid identifier. If I put class c after event x, then it says column ambiguously defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should first select the top-4 classes ordered by price and then in a outer SQL get the event data

```
select evt.*, top_classes.price, top_classes.class_name
from event evt,
       (select class_id, price, class_name
          from (select price, class_id, class_name
              from class 
             order by price DESC)
      where rownum <=4) top_classes
where evt.class_id = top_classes.class_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a join in your `WHERE EXISTS` subquery. Maybe putting it in a `WITH` clause would help?

```
WITH c1 AS ( -- Top 4 prices?
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT price, class_id
          FROM class
         ORDER BY price DESC
    ) WHERE rownum <= 4
)
SELECT x.*, c.price, c.class_name
  FROM event x, class c
 WHERE x.class_id = c.class_id
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM c1 WHERE c1.class_id = c.class_id )
```

But I think it is done even more easily this way:

```
WITH c1 AS (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT class_id, class_name, price
          FROM class
         ORDER BY price DESC
    ) WHERE rownum <= 4
)
SELECT x.*, c1.price, c1.class_name
  FROM event x, c1
 WHERE x.class_id = c1.class_id
```

Hope this helps.